# Which persistent storage is used by Dataflow to keep persistent state implemented with Apache Beam Timers?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

It is not said explicit but I suppose that Dataflow could use [Persistent Disk Resources](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#persistent-disk-resources)

Anyway I can not find confirmation for that.

I wonder if I could assume that limitations and expected performance for using Timers is equal to that provided here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow uses Persistent disks to store timers. But there's also a significant amount of caching involved so performance should be better than just reading from persistent disks.

Comment: Thank you for your response, is it documented somehow?

Comment: I don't think it's documented given that it's an implementation detail but I'll check with relevant folks :)