# Dataflow - State persistence?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

We are considering using Beam/Dataflow for stateful processing, but a bit concerned about the limited visibility on the state backend. How are states persisted on disk in case memory does not suffice ? Any underlying database ?

I heard about *Windmill* during a 2021 event [1], but a ticket from 2019 [2] refers to *Persistent Disk*.

Thanks !

[1] https://beamcollege.dev/
[2] [Which persistent storage is used by Dataflow to keep persistent state implemented with Apache Beam Timers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55471437/which-persistent-storage-is-used-by-dataflow-to-keep-persistent-state-implemente)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windmill and persistent storage on disk are the same thing. Windmill stores pipeline state on Persistent Disks.

> Windmill is a process running on user VMs in streaming Dataflow jobs. It is responsible for performing the streaming shuffle between workers, persisting and maintaining the consistency of pipeline state.

*(Non public source)*

You can find more details on [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69840804/13248738).

Comment: Thanks. Please make it explicit that this reference is not public and that is your private source. Interesting would also be to have other references about windmill.

Comment: Thanks ! May I ask where this source come from and why isn't is disclosed ? It would bring much more confidence and market traction to have more specs published for GCP, no ?

Comment: Can you please link to a resource that provides more insight into how the state is persisted on disk and how the state is transferred when a pipeline is updated? Thanks