# Dataflow - State persistence database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, persistence, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

We are considering using Beam/Dataflow for stateful processing:

- Real-time aggregation of metrics on global windows (every 1min)
- Real-time aggregation on a high number of parallel sessions (> 1 mio)

Example: get max price article bought for each 1 mio clients since registered on a portal

Also, we would also like to access those calculated aggregates while not interfering with the real-time job.

Design question : can it be covered by the current state back-end - Windmill/Persistent Disks [1] - or would the use of a database (like BigTable) be a better fit ?

Thanks !

[1] [Dataflow - State persistence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837451/dataflow-state-persistence/69846214#69846214)

Comment: If you need such control about the storage layer, dataflow might now be the right product to use. When asking in stackex, I recomment also explaining the context (why do you need satefullness on your pipeline? why do you need that control on the storage layer?). This will avoid the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). You've already asked 4 questions about doing things outside of the standard Beam, so maybe you should explain what limitations you're facing in order to receive better answers.

Comment: Question refactored to clarify requirements.

Comment: For design and architecture doubts, since there are no code doubts related (check [Help Centre "What's on Topic"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), StackOverflow could not be the best place to ask. Try asking on [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually possible to define [Big Table connectors](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-dataflow-java) in Dataflow to perform reading and writing operations.
Moreover, there is the [project.jobs.get method](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/get) of the Dialogflow API that returns an [instance of a job](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#resource:-job) which is a json response containing also the “currentState” field.
Therefore I think you could build a sort of automation script to get this field value and then store it in Big Table database using the Big Table connectors, however it is a quite complex solution and I am not sure if it could be convenient.

Comment: Still needs crafting to be brought alive, but so far the only (viable) answer ! Glad to hear more if you have a concrete example using this approach.